# How to Implement Active Directory Authentication in ASP.NET Web API Through Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, directoryservices

I've been reading a lot of guides/articles but haven't found one yet that does exactly what I want... that is to implement Active Directory Authentication in an ASP.NET Web API through forms.

Something like on this guide:

[Cool MVC 5 guide to implement authentication with Active Directory](http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/)

Which is very good but it's for MVC, i.e., it uses a Controller not an ApiController

Can someone please give me hints/tips/articles on how to start? Especially about the part that connects to the active directory. I've been stuck on this for a while.

UPDATE:

```
public bool IsAuthenticatedUser(string srvr, string usr, string password)
       {
           bool authenticated = false;

           try {
               DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(srvr, usr, password);
               object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
               Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
               authenticated = true;
           }
           catch {
               throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
           }
           return authenticated;
       }

       // POST: api/Login
       public void Post([FromBody]string username, [FromBody]string password)
       {
           if (IsAuthenticatedUser("LDAP string", username, password))
           {
               Redirect("Index");
           }
           else
           {
               throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
           }
       }
```

I was thinking of trying something like this for the authentication, your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think it's correct to make **FORMS** authentication for **WebApi**.
The sense of **WebApi** is working with data in **RESTful** manner.

So my suggestion is (if you want to use **AD FORMS** authentication):

*1)* Create test environment to test **AD** authentication - for this purpose, you may use Oracle **VirtualBox**. On it, you want to install **Windows Server 2016** (evaluation for 180 days), where you build AD, create domain and add some test users to it, install **AD SSL** certificate (hand-made is OK);

*2)* Install the certificate from 1) on host machine for **SSL** connections between host and virtual PCs (since you gonna send plain credentials);

*3)* In your Web Application, you make traditional **MVC** login page, using **SSL** cookie to store credential information: you create this cookie in your **Authenticate** controller method. The process of authentication is as simple as writing correct connection string in **web.config** for **System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider**, checking user validity is an ordinary **Membership.ValidateUser** method;

*4)* Once the user is successfully validated, use the saved cookie to validate the user between inner **WebApi** requests